# É recomendável utilizar ao TFS para quem está iniciando e tem um projeto simples?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Recentemente conclui o meu primeiro projeto em C#, trata-se de uma ferramenta que auxiliará o administrador da empresa onde trabalho.

No momento, as atualizações são manuais e em busca de achar uma solução para isso me deparei com o **Team Foundation Server**. Deveria eu começar a utilizá-lo para controlar as versões do meu sistema e até mesmo (caso possível) realizar atualizações automáticas?

Comment: Você fiz utilizar o TFS apenas para o código do sistema ou utilizar todas as funções que o mesmo possui?

Comment: Não sei todas as funções, conheço algumas como o controle de versão. Sei que consigo acessar as informações do TFS através de algumas linhas de código, penso em utilizar isso para reportar erros e, caso possível, pegar o meu projeto compilado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O TFS é mais que uma ferramenta de versionamento, você poderá utiliza-lo para gerenciar todo o projeto e demais projetos.

Você conseguirá usar Kanban para organizar as tarefas e diversos outros métodos para ajudar a organizar. Como por exemplo listar os bugs encontrados e associa-los para alguém fazer e também novos recursos que serão adicionados ao sistema.

Por ser tratar de uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento colaborativa mais de uma pessoa poderá lhe ajudar a gerir o projeto.

Com isso você poderá quantificar o tempo de desenvolvimento, quem trabalhou mais e assim por diante.

Vale lembrar que o TFS suporta qualquer linguagem de programação.

Eu recomendo a utilização principalmente pela gestão e controle.

- [Automatizando o processo de build](http://www.devmedia.com.br/automatizando-o-processo-de-build-revista-net-magazine-101/26746)
- [Integração Contínua com Team Foundation Server (deploy de um WebSite 
  ASP.NET MVC + IIS)](http://www.rodolfofadino.com.br/2014/02/integracao-continua-com-team-foundation-server-deploy-de-um-website-asp-net-mvc-iis/)
- [Deploy para FTP usando o TFS Build](http://www.leandroprado.com.br/2012/06/deploy-para-ftp-usando-o-tfs-build/)

Comment: No geral parece uma ótima ferramenta. Então, começarei a utilizar, mesmo trabalhando sozinho. Como minha busca inicial era por uma atualização automática do meu sistema, gostaria de saber qual é sua recomendação para esse tipo de situação, devo eu utilizar o servidor do TFS para atualizar meu sistema de alguma maneira? O que você recomendaria?

Comment: Sim, utilize os servidores da microsoft para isso, até por que não há gasto! A minha recomendação quanto a atualização automática (automatização de build) é você configurar o trigger de acordo com a sua necessidade. Anexarei alguns artigos explicando de modo geral a automatização.

Answer (score 2):

SIm, o ideal é você utilizar algo como o **Team Foundation Server** (TFS), devido a gama de funcionalidades que ele lhe proporciona.

Sendo seu projeto pessoal (até mesmo de sua empresa e/ou clientes) eu sugiro utilizar o **Visual Studio Team Services** ou VSTS.

Qual a diferença entre o TFS e o Visual Studio Team Services? Vejamos algumas:

1. O TFS é instalado  em seus servidores, todo configurado por você, você precisa se responsabilizar por Backups, Atualizações, etc. Já no VSTS, tudo isso está hospedado no Cloud da Microsoft, e é gerenciado pela mesma, ou seja, Backup, Updates, Instalação, etc, não fica sob sua jurisdição, você não se preocupa com isso, e não tem o custo de manter servidores ligados, etc.
2. O VSTS é atualizado *automagicamente* a cada 3 semanas, sem nenhuma intervenção sua, já o TFS demora no minimo 3 meses para sair um pacote de Updates, ou seja, a defasagem de versão será muito menor se você utilizar o VSTS.

Outro ponto bacana, é que o VSTS é gratuito para times com até 5 desenvolvedores, então se você tiver um time pequeno, seu custo será muito baixo.

Ali em cima, falei da Gama de Funcionalidades que o VSTS/TFS possui, vejamos algumas delas:

1. Controle de Versões (Utilizando TFVC ou GIT), onde você pode ter ilimitados repositórios privados
2. Planejamento Ágil, onde você pode gerenciar todas as suas tarefas, todos seus Backlogs, e ainda criar vinculos com seus commits para ter uma maior rastreabilidade do trabalho realizado
3. Build Automatizado, onde seu projeto será compilado pelo servidor, com a última versão do seu código fonte no reposítorio, poderá realizar validações de arquitetura, testes automatizados, analises de qualidade
4. Deployment Automatizado em todos os seus ambientes, com ciclo de aprovação, etc
5. Repositório de Nuget/NPM privados
6. etc.

Vale lembrar, que você não necessita trabalhar apenas com projetos .Net, o VSTS/TFS suporta basicamente qualquer linguagem e projeto, ou seja, você pode trabalhar com seus projetos Java, Android, iOS, entre outros, inclusive, a compilação e deployment funcionam também em máquinas Linux, pois você pode instalar um agente de compilação e deployment em máquinas linux para atender este tipo de cenário.

Outro ponto bacana, é a integração com ferramentas externas, por exemplo, você pode integrar um Slack para receber notificações de Atividades, Builds, Deployments, pode integrar um SonarQube para analise de Qualidade dos seus projetos, etc.

Vou deixar aqui para você também, alguns conteúdos sobre o assunto:

- [Primeiros Passos com VSTS](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMFPOLE2cW1wynLrJqkAyfvCxRKsOqX-w) (Playlist)
- [Configurando Build Agent no Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RbvYP8C1kU)